# How to know which drawable resource to load in graphical layout?

Tags: android

In my XML Graphical Layout I set the screen to 3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1) 320x480 mdpi.
But it still uses my hdpi-drawable resource. I checked my mdpi folder and my scaled image is  there 70x70. But it uses my 105x105 image in the hdpi folder. Oddly, when I use the xhdpi and hdpi screens it works fine, they use their own drawables.

And another questions why does 10.1in WXGA (Tablet) 1280x800 mdpi use mdpi resources considering it is a tablet and has high resolution?

Sorry for my english, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `mdpi` stands for `medium dpi`, which means medium screen **density**, not resolution

Comment: Also see this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

Comment: Thanks for the replies. To Dmitry I was pointing out the 1280x800 resolution rather than the mdpi. Still, do you know why this happens?